# XHTML 1.0 transitional warning with c# inline code

Tags: c#, xhtml, inline-code

The following link throws a validation warning saying "attribute values must be enclosed in quotation marks.

```
href=http://<%= HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host %>/rss.aspx/>
```

This shows up fine in the browser and seems to behave correctly but visual studio is showing the validation warning. If I try:

```
href="http://<%= HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host %>/rss.aspx"/>
```

The browser doesn't detect the link. Where should my quotes be so I don't get a validation warning and the link still works?

Thanks

Comment: Define "The browser doesn't detect the link"

Comment: Why are you validating ASP.NET? It is the generated HTML that should be validated.

Comment: The link is selectable an goes to the correct the location i.e. http://mysite.com/rss.aspx

Comment: So what happens when "The browser doesn't detect the link"? Is the link not selectable? Does the link go to the wrong location?

Comment: In this case the rss button in internet explorer doesn't detect rss so the button is grayed out.

Comment: So what's the difference between the **HTML** that works and the HTML that doesn't? Don't look at server side code to debug a client side problem.

Comment: Actually I've checked in view source,  link doesn't work is because the whole href is being detected as string. href="http://&lt;%= HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host %>/rss.aspx"

Comment: Is this code in an HTML or `.aspx` page?

Answer (score 1):

By default Visual Studio 2010 will validate against XHTML 1.0 transitional.

For that standard, you need to quote all attributes (since XHTML is an XML dialect).

You can change the target schema to match the actual standard you are using:

[image: target schema dropdown]

If you are using HTML5 and you don't get the option, you can install the [Web Standards Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 SP1](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a15c3ce9-f58f-42b7-8668-53f6cdc2cd83):

> Web Standards Update provides the much wanted HTML5 & CSS3 support to Visual Studio 2010 SP1. It brings VS 2010 intellisense & validation as close to W3C specification as we could get via means of an extension.  The most notable supported features by this extension are:

Comment: If I am using XHTML1.1, is it possible to to use the inline code with quotes? Am I putting them in the wrong place?

Comment: @mjroodt - You should be able to. Whether in or out of quotes `<%=%>` works fine on markup that is not server side.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
 href="<%="http://"+ HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host +"/rss.aspx" %>
```